# JHipster 7.0.1 Generating Application from Blueprint Error

Tags: jhipster, jdl

I am getting below error when trying to use a locally-linked blueprint. The command I run is also below. Please advise.

Environment:

```
node --version -> v14.17.0
npm --version -> 6.14.13
jhipster --version -> 7.0.1
yo --version -> 3.1.1
```

Command I run:

```
jhipster import-jdl apps.jh --blueprints cassandra-blueprint
```

Error I get from above command:

```
ERROR! jhContext.setupServerOptions is not a function
TypeError: jhContext.setupServerOptions is not a function
    at new module.exports (/Users/amarppatel/workspace/saathratri-app-holder/jhipster-cassandra-blueprint/generators/common/index.js:20:19)
    at Environment.instantiate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:748:23)
    at Environment.create (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:720:17)
    at JHipsterCommonGenerator.composeWith (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:1182:42)
    at JHipsterCommonGenerator._composeBlueprint (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base-blueprint.js:348:37)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base-blueprint.js:248:41
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JHipsterCommonGenerator.instantiateBlueprints (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base-blueprint.js:247:18)
    at new JHipsterCommonGenerator (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/common/index.js:41:49)
    at Environment.instantiate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:748:23)
ERROR! jhContext.setupServerOptions is not a function
TypeError: jhContext.setupServerOptions is not a function
    at new module.exports (/Users/amarppatel/workspace/saathratri-app-holder/jhipster-cassandra-blueprint/generators/common/index.js:20:19)
    at Environment.instantiate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:748:23)
    at Environment.create (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:720:17)
    at JHipsterCommonGenerator.composeWith (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:1182:42)
    at JHipsterCommonGenerator._composeBlueprint (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base-blueprint.js:348:37)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base-blueprint.js:248:41
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JHipsterCommonGenerator.instantiateBlueprints (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base-blueprint.js:247:18)
    at new JHipsterCommonGenerator (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/common/index.js:41:49)
    at Environment.instantiate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:748:23)
INFO! Generator app child process exited with code 1
ERROR! Error executing app --reproducible --no-force --with-entities --no-dry-run --no-whitespace --no-bail --no-skip-regenerate --no-skip-yo-resolve --from-jdl --blueprints cassandra-blueprint --no-skip-cache --no-skip-install --no-force-install --no-ask-answered --no-defaults --no-skip-git
Error: Error executing app --reproducible --no-force --with-entities --no-dry-run --no-whitespace --no-bail --no-skip-regenerate --no-skip-yo-resolve --from-jdl --blueprints cassandra-blueprint --no-skip-cache --no-skip-install --no-force-install --no-ask-answered --no-defaults --no-skip-git
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/import-jdl.js:183:16)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
ERROR! jhContext.setupServerOptions is not a function
INFO! Generator app child process exited with code 1
TypeError: jhContext.setupServerOptions is not a function
    at new module.exports (/Users/amarppatel/workspace/saathratri-app-holder/jhipster-cassandra-blueprint/generators/common/index.js:20:19)
    at Environment.instantiate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:748:23)
    at Environment.create (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:720:17)
    at JHipsterCommonGenerator.composeWith (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:1182:42)
    at JHipsterCommonGenerator._composeBlueprint (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base-blueprint.js:348:37)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base-blueprint.js:248:41
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JHipsterCommonGenerator.instantiateBlueprints (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base-blueprint.js:247:18)
    at new JHipsterCommonGenerator (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/common/index.js:41:49)
    at Environment.instantiate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:748:23)
INFO! Generator app child process exited with code 1
```

Comment: After generator version 7.x many blueprints are don't work any more. I think `cassandra-blueprint` is not supported by 7.x

Comment: I created my own blueprint. So am linking to it locally. I got past the above error, I think by running the following commands: ```npm install chalk -g
 npm install commander -g
 npm install escape-string-regexp -g```

Comment: Am now getting ```Unhandled promise rejection at:
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/escape-string-regexp/index.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
```